# error in mpirun command

Tags: mpi

```
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 2 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD 
        with errorcode 1.

        NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
         You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
         exactly when Open MPI kills them.
           --------------------------------------------------------------------------
          --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        mpirun has exited due to process rank 2 with PID 19175 on
         node mosura15 exiting without calling "finalize". This may
            have caused other processes in the application to be
            terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
```

I am running a simulation. In MPI command, I found the above error. What is reason behind this. How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Check your input file. The error is right there. And if you are confident about your input file, then try to finish your input file code with "&end" instead of "/".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the 3rd instance of your program (id 2) crashed and didn't call `MPI_Finalize()` to close down, and so mpirun closed all the other copies of the program as well. Is there something causing that particular node to crash, or is it a different node each time?

Comment: Yes, it is different at each time.

Answer (score 3):

The message is pretty clear; rank 2 called MPI_Abort(), which stops the whole program.  You should be able to look in your code and find out under what error conditions the program calls MPI_Abort().